# SystemVerilog: Packing and then unpacking with streaming operator gives ERROR: "wrong element type in unpacked array concatenation" in Vivado

Tags: hdl, vivado

I'm trying to pack a 2D unpacked array, pass it through a Verilog wrapper and unpack it in the other module (or testbench). The simplest code is as follows:

```
module a_tb();
  timeunit 10ns;
  timeprecision 1ns;

  localparam N     = 4;
  localparam WIDTH = 8;

  logic [N*N*WIDTH-1:0] A_flat_1;
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] A_1 [N][N];

  logic [N*N*WIDTH-1:0] A_flat_2;
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] A_2 [N][N];

  assign {<<{A_flat_1}} = A_1;
  assign A_flat_2 = A_flat_1;
  assign A_2 = {<<{A_flat_2}};    // Line 13

  initial begin
    foreach (A_1[i,j]) begin
      A_1[i][j] = 10*i+j;
    end

    #10;
    $display("%p", A_1);
    $display("%p", A_2);
    assert(A_1==A_2);
  end
endmodule
```

And I get the following error in Vivado 2018.2 Simulator:

```
ERROR: [VRFC 10-1571] wrong element type in unpacked array concatenation [U:/path/array_test.tb.sv:13]
```

From what I understand about the streaming operators, this should work. Could this be a tool bug?

Comment: This could be a tool bug. Try your code with another simulator on www.EDAplayground.com

Comment: @dave_59 It's a tool bug. it works in VCS. Thanks a lot. I've posted an answer with a workaround that works in both.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Vivado Simulator. The syntax works in Synposis VCS (EDA playground).

After days of experimentation, I found in Vivado Simulator, `{<<{A_flat_2}}` simply reverses the bits while keeping it packed, hence returns a `logic [N*N*WIDTH-1:0]` vector.

As a workaround, I figured out that `{>>{{<<{A_flat_2}}}}` returns an unpacked vector of type `logic [WIDTH-1:0] A_2 [N][N]`.

**Workaround (works both in VCS and Vivado)**

```
module a_tb();
  timeunit 10ns;
  timeprecision 1ns;
  
  localparam N     = 4;
  localparam WIDTH = 8;

  logic [N*N*WIDTH-1:0] A_flat_1;
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] A_1 [N][N];
  logic [N*N*WIDTH-1:0] A_flat_2;
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] A_2 [N][N];

  assign {<<{A_flat_1}} = A_1;
  assign A_flat_2 = A_flat_1;
  assign A_2 = {>>{{<<{A_flat_2}}}};

  initial begin
    foreach (A_1[i,j]) begin
      A_1[i][j] = 10*i+j;
    end
    #10;
    $display("%p", A_1);
    $display("%p", A_2);
    assert(A_1==A_2);
  end
endmodule
```